# Getting this error while Importing products table into into my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

While importing one of the table named products into my database. I am getting this issue.

> Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit
> the same file and import will resume.

I had tried clicking on resubmitting the same file. but in the end, few data from the table were missing.
I had tried making $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300; to $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0; in phpMyAdmin/libraries/config.default.php but  after that while importing it goes on infinite loop (Importing does not stops.)
Is there any solution by which I can import my table to my database?

Answer (score 1):

How big is the file?

One thing that can help is to import an uncompressed file (.sql) rather than some compressed format such as .gz or .zip. However, for some large files, it's quite difficult for phpMyAdmin to work around the resource limits the web server imposes (including memory use, execution time, etc). You can increase the resource limits to phpMyAdmin or directly in the webserver and PHP configurations, but in my opinion that's mostly a workaround and it's difficult to get feedback about the progress as the import is occurring.

There is also a feature of phpMyAdmin called the [UploadDir](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_UploadDir) that lets you import a file that's already on the server in a special folder, which can speed up the process so it doesn't run in to the resource limits as quickly.

My best suggestion is to use the command line client to perform any large import (or export) operation.